# Unsplit family of rational curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth Fano variety of Picard number one. Let $K$ be an irreducible component of rational curves in $X$ of degree $d$ such that for any two points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ there is a rational curve $C \in K$ containing $x_1, x_2$.

Question: Is $K$ an un-split family ?

Comment: Mori’s theorem guarantees that some specializations are reducible or non-reduced as soon as the amticanonical degree is as positive as the dimension of the Fano manifold.